# why does Android codelab 03.2 expect an IllegalArgumentException when dividing doubles by zero?

Tags: java, android

In a simple calculator app, when dividing by zero with doubles, it returns "Infinity". I've done some research and found that Java does that for Doubles and Floats. For Integers it returns ArithmeticException. Why does the coding challenge for unit tests in the Android codelabs(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-unit-tests/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#4) seem to expect it to throw an IllegalArgumentException? is it because an update changed the standard for dividing by zero, and the codelabs need to be updated?

Need some clarity, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ArithmeticException) they say this about ArithmeticException:

> Thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition has occurred. For example, an integer "divide by zero" throws an instance of this class. ArithmeticException objects may be constructed by the virtual machine as if Throwable#Throwable(String, Throwable, boolean, boolean).

So my guess is they have to update the lab, yes.